# Informatica - SQ transformation

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

What will be the expected result of the below.

I have table A with column1,
I'm trying to map column1 to SQ, which has 3 columns - col1, col2 and col3.
Link Column1 to col1,col2 and col3 in SQ. Now when I try to generate SQL query for SQ, what will be the result?

Comment: Hi - I'm wondering what's stopping you trying this for yourself and seeing what happens?

Comment: Hi Nick, right now I don't have a right platform set to try this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since OP is waiting for answer and doesnt have informatica to test it out, let me answer to that.
if you connect one column to three columns in SQ and then connect all those three columns to next transformation, then your generated SQL will contain one column repeated thrice from source.
Here are some screenshot from a dummy map i created.
mapping screenshot -
[image: mapping]
Then here is generate SQL -
[image: Generated SQL]

```
SELECT 
ITEM.ITEM_NUM, ITEM.ITEM_NUM, ITEM.ITEM_NUM 
FROM
 ITEM
```